# Change select fake placeholder color when option is selected - Pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got a simple select element with a fake/placeholder. I want to have the placeholder in a grey color. Once a option is selected I want to change the color to black.

I do know that I can archive this by adding the **required** state to my select element and in my CSS I add:

**But** my question is can I archive this without having to require the field?
If possible I would prefer a pure CSS solution.

```css
select {
    color: black;
}
select:required:invalid {
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<select id="select" required>
    <option disabled selected hidden value="">Please select value</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with just CSS.